# Get form-data for Django tests

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to test a Django form, without spelling out myself all the POSTed data that would normally go into it.

In a real application, this data would be provided by the browser, based on the form as rendered (as HTML) by Django.

How do I get the data without going through the browser?

```
form0 = MyForm(instance=obj)  #  form which would be shown in normal usage
data = the_magic_function(form0)  #  data which would be posted if user just pressed submit right away

# potentially manipulate some parts of this data to make the test interesting

form1 = MyForm(instance=obj, data=data)

# actual tests are on form1
```

`form.initial` is kinda what I'm looking for, but not quite: it contains Python objects rather than strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but this code snippet might help you nonetheless. I use it for creating new POST data from a form response. For example, to resubmit the corrected form when the form validation failed.

```py
import lxml.html

def form_data(response: HttpResponse, **kwargs) -> dict:
    return parse_html_form(response.content, **kwargs)


def parse_html_form(html: str, **kwargs) -> dict:
    """Returns form data as a dict.

    The form lookup can be narrowed down by using attributes to filter for
    as `kwargs`.
    """
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

    filter = " and ".join(f"@{key}='{val}'" for key, val in kwargs.items())
    form = tree.xpath(f"//form[{filter}]" if filter else "//form")[0]

    data = {}
    for key, element in form.inputs.items():
        match element.value:
            case lxml.html.CheckboxValues():
                data[key] = [sub.value for sub in element.value.group if sub.value]
            case lxml.html.MultipleSelectOptions():
                data[key] = list(element.value)
            case _:
                data[key] = element.value or ""
    return data
```

You could use it on the rendered form:

```py
form0 = MyForm(instance=obj)
data = parse_from_html(form0.as_div())
```